# Error in MATLAB sequentialfs while selecting features from 94*263 feature vectors

Tags: matlab, feature-selection, svd

I have 94 samples with 263 features for each sample. The total feature vector is 94*263 in size. There are no NaN or Inf value in the feature vectors.  There are two classes (51 in class a and 43 in class b). I am using sequentialfs to select features but I am getting the following error each time:

```
Error using crossval>evalFun (line 480)
The function '@(XT,yT,Xt,yt)(sum(~strcmp(yt,classify(Xt,XT,yT,'quadratic'))))'     generated the following error:
The input to SVD must not contain NaN or Inf.
```

The code is:

```
X = FEATUREVECTOR;
y = LABELS;
c = cvpartition(y,'k',10);
opts = statset('display','iter');
fun = @(XT,yT,Xt,yt)...
      (sum(~strcmp(yt,classify(Xt,XT,yT,'quadratic'))));
[fs,history] = sequentialfs(fun,X,y,'cv',c,'options',opts)
```

Can you please tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling sequentialfs with some inputs, that MAY be vaguely related to the mess of random numbers we see in your question. Beyond that, I can't read anything from your mind. If you want help you need to show what you did.

I change input data and it works well,

```
load fisheriris;
X = randn(150,10);
X(:,[1 3 5 7 ])= meas;
y = species;

c = cvpartition(y,'k',10);
opts = statset('display','iter');
fun = @(XT,yT,Xt,yt)...
      (sum(~strcmp(yt,classify(Xt,XT,yT,'quadratic'))));

[fs,history] = sequentialfs(fun,X,y,'cv',c,'options',opts)
```

Your input data has problem.